# A Question On Triple Integration

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, convex-optimization

Can anyone construct a nonzero continuous function $f:[0, 1]\times[0, 1]\times [0, 1]\rightarrow [0, \infty)$ such that 
\begin{equation*}
\int_{t_1=0}^1 \int_{t_2=0}^1 \int_{t_3=0}^1 f(t_1, t_2, t_3)~ \Big(t_1 + t_3 - 5\Big) \mathrm{d}t_3\mathrm{d}t_2\mathrm{d}t_1 = 0~? 
\end{equation*}

Comment: Giving some context and self effort already invested in the questions can help both to hook up people's interest in the question and to know what have you already achieved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As $t_1 + t_3 - 5\le 1 + 1 - 5 = -3$ in the integration domain, is impossible.

Comment: @ Martin: I am not convinced, since in the domain of integration \begin{equation*} f(t_1, t_2, t_3) (t_1 + t_3 - 5) \leq 0. \end{equation*}

Comment: Supposing your answer is correct, can you construct a nonzero continuous function $f:[0, 1]\times[0, 1]\times [0, 1]\rightarrow [0, \infty)$ such that 
\begin{equation*}
\int_{t_1=0}^1 \int_{t_2=0}^1 \int_{t_3=0}^1 f(t_1, t_2, t_3)~ \Big(t_1 + t_3 - 2\Big) \mathrm{d}t_3\mathrm{d}t_2\mathrm{d}t_1 = 0~? 
\end{equation*}

Comment: @user144660, if $f$ is nonzero, $f>0$ in some ball and $f(t_1,t_2,t_3)(t_1+t_3−5)<0$ in the ball.

Comment: This answer is correct and the person having downvoted it clearly doesn't understand mathematics: since $f \ge 0$ and the quantity between brackets is $<0$, the integrand will be $\le 0$, so its integral will also be $\le 0$. Since the integral is supposed to be $0$, the only possibility for the integrand is to be $0$ almost everywhere, thus $f=0$ almost everywhere. Since $f$ is continuous, it is $0$ everywhere, therefore there is no such $f$ as required by the problem.